# Appropriate Test for Statistical Significant Change in Values Over Time

Tags: regression, time-series, statistical-significance, spss

I have four number of values for number of policies within a given field put forward in a given year. I want to find if there is a statistically significant increase or decline in the number of policies over time.

My initially approach was to try and run a t-test on the values, but I believe that that was wrong as I used percentage values compared to total number of policies.

What would be the best way to find statistical significance? I think I may have been trying to over complicate things that that this only needs simple regression.