# How do I measure the significance of a trend

Tags: time-series

I have a 5 year dataset by month, so I have 69 discrete measures of the same value. That value shows an increasing trend, but I'm unsure how to measure it's significance. My team would also like a p value. Apologies for the inexp to language, can anyone guide me? In Excel would make my life easier.

Comment: This is an awfully broad subject: you are asking for a synopsis of the theory and practice of time series analysis, without giving even qualitative details of your data or your objectives.  Please, at a minimum, edit this post to provide some context and information that will help direct and focus the answers.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/147270/36423

Comment: thanks for the advice whuber, this is a case of not even knowing what I don't know. But Repmat has given me the direction that I needed - ie I create a 'dummy' dependent variable - feels like cheating but it works perfectly and I even understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy, you include a trend as a dependent variable (DV) in the regression. Simply plot y over the period, and decide on the appropriate trend. Say it is linear, then you include a DV that starts with 1 in the first periode, is 2 in the second period, and ends with 69 in the last period.

If you decide on a qudratic trend, then include: $1^2$, $2^2$, ... , $69^2$.
You could also do an exponential trend, basically what ever you can imagine. But linear, exponential and quadratic are normally the only ones needed.

Infenrece does not change! And so the regression add-in in Excel will calculate the confidence level, and p-value the same as for any other DV. You might get a very large $R^2$, and you should not overstate the importance of this.

EDIT: I might also add that, in most time series aplications it is wrong to not include a trend. Why? Because regression (espcially OLS/GLS) will pick  up a strong relationship, but in reality you just a have trending (spurious) relationship.